# Fatal error in Game Maker: variable not set before reading it

Tags: game-maker

I have been following the tutorial videos on game maker, and I am at the part where he explains how to get the bullet under the character. I thought I did everything right. He then tested the game, and it worked. But when I played, and tried to shoot, this message appeared:

---

#

FATAL ERROR in
action number 1
of  Step Event0
for object obj_player:

Variable obj_player.layer_bullet(100002, -2147483648) not set before reading it.
 at gml_Object_obj_player_Step_0 (line 30) -        instance_create_layer(x, y, layer_bullet, obj_bullet);

#

Comment: Have you created a layer with name `layer_bullet` in [room](http://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/2_interface/1_editors/rooms.html) or using [layer_create()](http://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/4_gml_reference/rooms/layers/layer_create.html) function?

Answer (score 2):

Layers have to be referenced via their name, provided as a string. Try changing your create function in the step event to

```
instance_create_layer(x, y, "layer_bullet", obj_bullet
```